# What is the user-agent string for Firefox beta for android?

Tags: javascript, android

I can't test it because my Android isn't supported.

Thanks!

Comment: Why my actual test result not to be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:13.0) Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0

You can find a full reference on the Mozilla dev pages [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference#Mobile_and_Tablet_indicators)

Answer (score 2):

I had wrote a small php script to echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

and I install the Firfox beta on my android device Sumsang I9003.

found the answer is

Mozilla/5.0(Android verison); Linux version Gecko/20120123 Firefox/10.0 Fennec/10.0

[image]